# How to fit this model

Tags: fitting

I have such `data`

```
data={{0.`,0.19119623`},{60.`,0.490687616`},{120.`,0.568493204`},
{180.`,0.58938258`},{360.`,0.619697527`},{540.`,0.652197922`},
{720.`,0.670972024`},{900.`,0.687850059`},{1080.`,0.705285338`},
{1260.`,0.720122862`},{1860.`,0.757085288`},{2460.`,0.786117461`},
{3060.`,0.78913818`},{3660.`,0.812174321`}};
```

The model is to fit.

```
mod=(2+Exp[b x])/(1-Exp [2 b ((9.404 x)/a+c)])^d+a x-b;
```

When I try to `FindFit` it

```
FindFit[data, mod, {a, b, c, d}, x]
```

I'll get an error information and an error result

[image]

Can any suggestion given?

Comment: Don't you have better guesses for your parameters?

Comment: @J.M.  I don't have.If I find the suitable guesses,I'll update the post.

Comment: Try to get an idea about `d` first. A fractional `d` is the only source of complex number here. You can use some integral guess for `d` and choose different initial guess for other parameters.

Comment: This is the sort of function that interpolation works rather well under. `ibs = BSplineFunction[data];` `Show[ListPlot[data], 
 ParametricPlot[ibs[x], {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]]`
I think you have too many variables for the amount of data points to do this with fitting functions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: @m_goldberg Through the efforts of the whole day,I found the experimental data maybe have some mistake.It hard to fit that formula,So I give a close vote to this topic,too.

Comment: @Feyre Thanks for your advice.

Comment: If you just need a prediction for other values of `x`, then you might consider the following: `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], Log[data[[All, 2]]]}], {a + 
     b Log[x + c], c > 0}, {a, b, c}, x];
Show[ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {-100, 0}],
 Plot[Exp[nlm[x]], {x, 0, 3700}, PlotRange -> All]]
`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment.

Quite frankly, what you encountered is not (yet) a *Mathematica*-related problem: instead, you either have very poor starting points for your fitting, or a bad model altogether. You really MUST produce **more reasonable starting values** for your parameters. After all, you chose a very specific functional form, so you probably have some physical model in mind in which those parameters have some meaning.

You can use *Mathematica* to help you identify better values; perhaps you could set up a Manipulate to explore those conditions:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListPlot[data],
  Plot[-b + (2 + E^(b x)) (1 - E^(2 b (c + (9.404` x)/a)))^-d + a x, {x, 0, 3600}],
  PlotRange -> All
  ],
 {{a, 1}, -10, 10},
 {{b, 1}, -10, 10},
 {{c, 1}, -10, 10},
 {{d, 1}, -10, 10}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, $1$ is far from appropriate as a starting point for these parameters...

Comment: I apologise for my delayed response. I am aware that there are some unreliable in `data` it cause hard to fit that model as your this post.Anyway thanks you try for me.